# Lines on map when I change projection on QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system

I changed the projection of my base to WGS 84 PDC but I get these lines on top. This also happens to a few other projections. I am trying to make the Pacific the center of the map.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to save the base as another file with the projection desired? Click with right click,"Save as...", save as another file and selected the projection you want.

Comment: Thanks, Kleber. Yes, I've tried that but it has the same lines that overlap.